# Numpy needs the ucs2

Tags: linux, unicode, numpy, python-2.7, ucs

I have installed Numpy using ActivePython and when I try to import numpy module, it is throwing the following error:

> ImportError:
>   /opt/ActivePython-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so:
>   undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode

I am fairly new to python, and I am not sure what to do. I appreciate if you could point me to the right direction.

- Should I remove python and configure its compilation with the
  "--enable-unicode=ucs2" or "--with-wide-unicode" option?

Cheers

---

- OS: Fedora 16, 64bit;
- Python version: Python 2.7.2 (default, Mar 26 2012, 10:29:24);
- The current compile Unicode version: ucs4

Comment: Any particular reason you went for ActivePython instead of using the system Python?

Comment: I agree with Ignacio - any reason to not use the system Python 2.7.2?

Comment: No particular reason. It was just a convenient choice at the time. I have python-pip installed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that a quick solution to these sort of complications is that you use the Enthought Python Distribpotion (EPD) on Linux which includes a wide range of extensions. Cheers.