# Build numpy with ucs4 issue

Tags: linux, numpy, python-2.7, ucs

I've installed successfully python2.7 with ucs4 format.

If I install the numpy with: sudo pip install --upgrade numpy, it works and I can use it, but installing by this way only put numpy in my dist-packages, however it's needed to be in site-packages. (because Jepp can find them only there)

Thus I downloaded the numpy tar file, I buildt it (sudo python setup.py build) and installed it (sudo python setup.py install), but it gives me undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode. It seems for me, it installed numpy with ucs2.

How could I force to install numpy with ucs4?
(I've read this article: [Numpy needs the ucs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929170/numpy-needs-the-ucs2) but EPD is not the solution for me)

Any idea may help me!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I simply copied the installed files from dist-packages to site packages. If someone has a better solution, please inform me.